# how to pass id name html to js function

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to pass id name html to js function by i have code html :

```
<ul>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:animal()">
    <span class="animal" id="ani 1">dog</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:animal()">
    <span class="animal" id="ani 2">dog</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:animal()">
    <span class="animal" id="ani 2">dog</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

i want id name of span tag for some thing. How to pass it to function?

Comment: You'll need to decide *when* you want that to happen and set up an event handler for that moment in time that scans the DOM and extracts the data.

Comment: Step 1 : `javascript:animal(this)`, Step 2 : `function animal(elem){ console.log(elem.firstChild.id) }`

Comment: it's bad that the id contains space...

Comment: Don´t use href = "javascript..."; use onclick = "animal()" instead; don´t use id to pass information, use data-id, or something else ... id attribute is the element identifier, you can use any custom tag you want, id has its own purpose.

Comment: Please note that the `id` of an element must be unique. You have two _dogs_ with the same `id`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Allot here needs to be fixed up

1) Id is something you want to be unique and only have one of

2) Use the `onclick` attribute for handling Javascript functions.

3) The easiest way of passing in the `id` of the element for the sake of this example is to pass it as an argument.

Bellow is an example of how I may go about what you're asking for. However having your Javascript use even listeners is generally a better practice.

```
    <ul>
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="animal('ani1')">
     <span class="animal" id="ani1" >dog</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="animal('ani2')">
   <span class="animal" id="ani2">dog</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
 <a href="#" onclick="animal('ani1')">
  <span class="animal" id="ani3">dog</span>
 </a>
</li>
```

A better method if you're willing to write a little bit more Javascript would be to detect the child element's `id` in the `animal` function like so.

```
function animal(){
   var id = this.childNodes.querySelector('span').id;
}
```

This would allow to not have to write the `id` name in as an argument to the function.

Comment: You have removed the link so you can no longer tab into the element and press enter...

Comment: @Endless, fair enough I'll make some edit to make use of the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use "event.target.id", this will give you the ID of element.

Comment: the id is on the child element

Comment: Then we can do <span onClick=func(this.id) class="animal" id="ani 2">dog</span>

Comment: but OP wants it to be on the link elm, you can't tab into a span and press enter

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

The first being, if your markup is static and you're calling functions exactly as you are in your example, you can just pass in the ID as an argument to your `animal()` function like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:animal('ani-1')">
      <span class="animal" id="ani-1">dog</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:animal('ani-2')">
      <span class="animal" id="ani-2">dog</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:animal('ani-3')">
      <span class="animal" id="ani-3">dog</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use the argument in your javascript like so:

```
function animal(animalId) {
  console.log('the animal\'s id is' + animalId);
}
```

Another option is to use jQuery and add functionality to the elements through a custom `data-` attribute like so.

```
<li>
  <span class="animal" id="ani-1" data-animal>dog</span>
</li>

// In your javascript
$('[data-animal]').on('click', function(event) {
  var animalId = event.target.id;
});
```

There are a few other ways you can do it, but how you intend to use the ID, and how you intend to build your markup can and will determine the best approach for you to take.